# Нужно сделать что-то вроде калькулятора. Не могу понять как это реализовать. Изучаю язык около 2 месяцев

Tags: c#

На форме 4 кнопки (+2;+1;-1;+1) каждая выполняет своё действие. В конце должно вывестись число. Выполняться должна цепочка действий (например, 2+1+1+1-2+1-2). Пыталась сделать так, но считает не правильно.

```
 int a = 0;
    int b;
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b = a + 1;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(b);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b = b + 2;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(b);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b = b - 1;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(b);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b = b - 2;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При нажатии на кнопку вы должны считать старое значение, модифицировать его и записать обратно

```
private void Add(int addend) {
  int val = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text);
  val = val + addend;
  label1.Text = Convert.ToString(val);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Add(1);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Add(2);
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Add(-1);
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Add(-2);
}
```

Или хранить результат где-то отдельно, чтобы каждый раз не вызывать `Convert.ToInt32`

```
int val = 0;

private void Add(int addend) {
  val = val + addend;
  label1.Text = Convert.ToString(val);
}
```